# Cors error persists if the page is not refreshed in Nuxt

Tags: cors, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, zendesk-api

I just started to learn Nuxt.
I have a CORS issue when I try to access a page by `<nuxt-link>`.
The problem is solved if I refresh the page or I do it via `<a href="">`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ author }}</p>
    <button @click="$fetch">Fetch</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent,
  useFetch,
  useContext,
  ref
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ArticleAuthor',
  setup() {
    const author: any = ref(null)
    const { $http, $config } = useContext()
    const apiSecret = Buffer.from($config.apiSecret).toString('base64')
    const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {
      author.value = await $http.$get(
        `https://zendeskhelpsandbox.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/1904135029254`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${apiSecret}`
          }
        }
      )
    })
    return { author, fetch }
  }
})
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What does the error message (in your browser's Console tab) say?

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://zendeskhelpsandbox.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/1904135029254' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: What is `.toString('base64')` doing here? Try to use it hardcoded directly, just to be sure. Also, please do not use `a`, only `nuxt-link` is valid for a SPA/Nuxt app here. The error is coming mainly from the fact that you are doing a client side navigation with a `nuxt-link`, while the initial request is done on the server (where you will not have any CORS). Also, check your network tab (what you're sending, receiving) and be sure that your backend have your Nuxt's app IP whitelisted.

Comment: The endpoint in question doesn't appear to be CORS-aware. I can't see any CORS headers in the response to a preflight request.

Comment: Do you have reverse proxy in place? It seems like app is running on localhost:3000, I would I would try this in fetch /api/v2/users/1904135029254, simply lose domain

Comment: Thanks for your help
i changed the headers like this :
`headers: {Authorization: `Basic ${apiSecret}`,Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I used Proxy and added an `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`

```html
<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent,
  useFetch,
  useContext,
  ref
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ArticleAuthor',
  setup() {
    const author: any = ref(null)
    const { $http, $config } = useContext()
    const apiSecret = Buffer.from($config.apiSecret).toString('base64')
    const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {
      author.value = await $http.$get(
          `/api/users/1904135029254`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Basic ${apiSecret}`,
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
          }
        )
    })
    return { author, fetch }
  }
})
</script>
```